# Multiple try codes in one block

Tags: python, exception, try-catch, except

I have a problem with my code in the try block.
To make it easy this is my code:

```
try:
    code a
    code b #if b fails, it should ignore, and go to c.
    code c #if c fails, go to d
    code d
except:
    pass
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: To be explicit, you want `code c` to be executed *only when code b raises an exception*?

Comment: All codes should be run, in one try block, even if they raise an exception.

Comment: You cannot have that. A `try` block is not there to suppress exceptions across all code executed. It'll let you *catch* the exception when it happens, but the rest of the block is never executed.

Comment: Okay, good to know. So per code an try block

Answer (score 199, accepted):

You'll have to make this *separate* `try` blocks:

```
try:
    code a
except ExplicitException:
    pass

try:
    code b
except ExplicitException:
    try:
        code c
    except ExplicitException:
        try:
            code d
        except ExplicitException:
            pass
```

This assumes you want to run `code c` *only* if `code b` failed.

If you need to run `code c` *regardless*, you need to put the `try` blocks one after the other:

```
try:
    code a
except ExplicitException:
    pass

try:
    code b
except ExplicitException:
    pass

try:
    code c
except ExplicitException:
    pass

try:
    code d
except ExplicitException:
    pass
```

I'm using `except ExplicitException` here because it is **never** a good practice to blindly ignore all exceptions. You'll be ignoring `MemoryError`, `KeyboardInterrupt` and `SystemExit` as well otherwise, which you normally do not want to ignore or intercept without some kind of re-raise or conscious reason for handling those.

Comment: Python's exception handling is just so ugly, it makes you write code that cries for C-style macros.

Comment: @Elazar: When your code starts to look like the above, you really want to rethink what you are doing. With context managers and some refactoring, most exception-handling code can be made much more readable and maintainable.

Comment: The question is, should I rethink it just because it is python so I must use both exceptions and indentation. Four simple operations, each should execute only if the last failed, and you get 4 levels of indentation. uh. If exceptions are good, their use should have been syntactically encouraged.

Comment: Refactoring is nice, but it comes with other issues like binding and scoping.

Comment: There is just not enough detail in the OP to go into possible alternatives.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: still, some links to relevant context manager usage that might help in a case like this might be nice.

Comment: @naught101: it's way, way too broad to give anything as focused as links to relevant context manager usage. The best I can think of is [talks by Raymond Hettinger that demonstrate code refactorings that use context managers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wf-BqAjZb8M).

Comment: @MartijnPietersthat's great, thanks. Relevant part around 20 minutes in.

Answer (score 55):

You can use [fuckit](https://github.com/ajalt/fuckitpy#as-a-decorator) module.
Wrap your code in a function with `@fuckit` decorator:

```
@fuckit
def func():
    code a
    code b #if b fails, it should ignore, and go to c.
    code c #if c fails, go to d
    code d
```

Comment: Will this try every one or stop after the first that successfully runs?

Comment: Why would anyone use this?

Comment: @jfleach: because it does precisely what the OP asked for. And it's funny.

Comment: As @Austin commented in his question: this will try and excute every part of the code. It won't stop after the first succesfull one.

Comment: Now I want to see the project where someone actually uses this, lol.

Answer (score 21):

Extract (refactor) your statements. And use the magic of `and` and `or` to decide when to short-circuit.

```
def a():
    try: # a code
    except: pass # or raise
    else: return True

def b():
    try: # b code
    except: pass # or raise
    else: return True

def c():
    try: # c code
    except: pass # or raise
    else: return True

def d():
    try: # d code
    except: pass # or raise
    else: return True

def main():   
    try:
        a() and b() or c() or d()
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: I think a decorator would fit here.

Comment: If `b` fails (raises an exception), `c` will **not** be executed, nor will `d`.

Comment: it is **Commented** it is just there as a comment.... could write `pass` too..... edited it, better?

Comment: I've asked for clarification from the OP as what he wants is ambiguous, but your code runs `c` even if `b` succeeds.

Comment: Okay that's what I thought, for each code I have to create a new try block. Because let's say I have several codes to be run, it should continue even if an exception occurs. Because what it does now, when the first exception occurs, when B fails, it will skip the other codes.Which is not what I want. Even if B fails it should try C, if C fails it should try D. No matter if error or not it should run through all lines. Hope it's better to understand now.

Comment: `except: pass ... else: return True` is an obscure way of implicitly saying `except: return None ... else: return True`. Better to be explicit.

Answer (score 10):

If you don't want to chain (a huge number of) try-except clauses, you may try your codes in a loop and break upon 1st success.

Example with codes which can be put into functions:

```
for code in (
    lambda: a / b,
    lambda: a / (b + 1),
    lambda: a / (b + 2),
    ):
    try: print(code())
    except Exception as ev: continue
    break
else:
    print("it failed: %s" % ev)
```

Example with arbitrary codes (statements) directly in the current scope:

```
for i in 2, 1, 0:
    try:
        if   i == 2: print(a / b)
        elif i == 1: print(a / (b + 1))
        elif i == 0: print(a / (b + 2))
        break        
    except Exception as ev:
        if i:
            continue
        print("it failed: %s" % ev)
```

Answer (score 5):

You could try a for loop

```py
for func,args,kwargs in zip([a,b,c,d], 
                            [args_a,args_b,args_c,args_d],
                            [kw_a,kw_b,kw_c,kw_d]):
    try:
       func(*args, **kwargs)
       break
    except:
       pass
```

This way you can loop as many functions as you want without making the code look ugly

Answer (score 4):

Lets say each code is a function and its already written then the following can be used to iter through your coding list and exit the for-loop when a function is executed without error using the "break".

```py
def a(): code a
def b(): code b
def c(): code c
def d(): code d

for func in [a, b, c, d]:  # change list order to change execution order.
   try:
       func()
       break
   except Exception as err:
       print (err)
       continue
```

I used "Exception " here so you can see any error printed. Turn-off the print if you know what to expect and you're not caring (e.g. in case the code returns two or three list items (i,j = msg.split('.')).

Comment: having thiem as a list of functions (that are already called) will immediately execute them in the list itself, before even reaching `try`

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem, but then it was doing the things in a loop which turned it into a simple case of issueing the `continue` command if successful. I think one could reuse that technique if not in a loop, at least in some cases:

```
while True:
    try:
        code_a
        break
    except:
        pass

    try:
        code_b
        break
    except:
        pass

    etc

    raise NothingSuccessfulError
```

Answer (score 1):

I use a different way, with a new variable:

```
continue_execution = True
try:
    command1
    continue_execution = False
except:
    pass
if continue_execution:
    try:
        command2
    except:
        command3
```

to add more commands you just have to add more expressions like this:

```
try:
    commandn
    continue_execution = False
except:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on kxr's answer (not enough rep to comment) you can use For/Else ([see docs](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html)) to avoid checking the `i` value. The `else` clause only executes when the `for` finishes normally, so it gets skipped when the `break` executes

```
for i in 2, 1, 0:
    try:
        if   i == 2: print(a / b)
        elif i == 1: print(a / (b + 1))
        elif i == 0: print(a / (b + 2))
        break        
    except Exception as ev:
        continue
else:
    print("it failed: %s" % ev)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Elazar suggested:
"I think a decorator would fit here."

```
# decorator
def test(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            func(*args, **kwargs)
        except: pass
    return inner

# code blocks as functions
@test
def code_a(x):
    print(1/x)

@test
def code_b(x):
    print(1/x)

@test
def code_c(x):
    print(1/x)

@test
def code_d(x):
    print(1/x)

# call functions
code_a(0)
code_b(1)
code_c(0)
code_c(4)
```

output:

```
1.0
0.25
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming each code block returns non-null value. (where you should design it to be)

```
val = None

try:
    val = func_a()
except (AErr, ...):
    expt_a()  # e.g. print('bad a')

try:
    val = val or func_b()
except (BErr, ...):
    expt_b()

try:
    val = val or func_c()
except (CErr, ...):
    expt_c()
```

if there are plenty of these structures, further simplify as

```
func_errs_expt_list = [
    [func_a, (AErr,...), expt_a],
    [func_b, (BErr,...), expt_b],
    [func_c, (CErr,...), expt_c],
    ...
]

val = None

for func, errs, expt in func_errs_expt_list:
    try:
        val = val or func(*args, **kwargs)
    except errs:
        expt(*args, **kwargs)
```

introducing oo to prettify elements is possible

```
class BaseExceptionSafeBlock:
    @staticmethod
    def _try(*args, **kwargs):
        raise NotImplementedError('return non-null')

    @staticmethod
    def _expected_errors(*args, **kwargs):
        return tuple()  # overridable

    @staticmethod
    def _except(e, *args, **kwargs):
        pass  # overridable

    @classmethod
    def try(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return cls._try(*args, **kwargs)
        except cls._expected_errors(*args, **kwargs) as e:
            cls._except(e, *args, **kwargs):
            return None


class ABlock(BaseExceptionSafeBlock):
    @staticmethod
    def _try(*args, **kwargs):
        # do something and return it

...

def execute(blocks, *args, **kwargs):
    for block in blocks:
        res = block.try(*args, **kwargs)
        if res is not None:
            return res
    return None


val = execute([ABlock, ...], *args, **kwargs)
```