# good way to generalize multiple try except

Tags: python, exception, try-catch, except, generalization

I have 15 try except statements in a for loop in the code. I think that it can be generalized but I am not able to get to the solution. How can I do it.

```
for item in results:

    try:
        a = item.something()
    except:
        a = ""

    try:
        b = item.something2()
    except:
        b = ""

    b = re.sub(r'\W+', ' ', b)
    b = b.strip()

    try:
        c = item.something3()
        parsed_url = urlparse(b)
        if not bool(parsed_url.scheme):
            break
    except:
        c = ""

    try:
        d = item.something4()
    except:
        d = ""
```

As suggested in the answer I generalized it to

```
def attrs(self, call_fun):
    try:
        return call_fun()
    except:
        return ""
```

But when I call

```
   a = self.attrs(item.get("data-a"))
```

I get a blank output whereas calling try: except: gives correct output.
Whats going wrong?

Comment: You may find this useful: [Multiple try codes in one block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17322208/multiple-try-codes-in-one-block)

Comment: never write `except:`, always be specific as to which exception you’re catching, i.e. `except AttributeError:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without changing your data:

```
def try_something(callable):
    try:
        return callable()
    except:
        return ""

a = try_something(item.something)
```

Remember that you can freely pass a callable (function or method) as a parameter to a Python function. This utilizes that. However, there may still a better way to do this by refactoring the class of `item`, but that would require more information.

Also, do you not know the type of exception being thrown? If you do, you should be more explicit in the `except` statement.

Answer (score 1):

The current accepted answer would only work if the callable did not take any arguments, to execute a small snippet and suppress a certain error it might raise it would be easier to use a context manager:

```
class catch:
    def __init__(self,err_type):
        valid = True
        if isinstance(err_type, tuple):
            valid = all(issubclass(e, BaseException) for e in err_type)
        else:
            valid = issubclass(err_type, BaseException)
        if not valid:
            raise TypeError("can only catch exception types, not {!r}".format(err_type))
        self.catch_err = err_type

    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __exit__(self,typ, err, tb):
        self.err = err #keep a reference if you want to access later.
        if isinstance(err, self.catch_err):
            return True
```

Then you can run your individual parts like this:

```
a = b = c = d = "" #default if any fail.

with catch(Exception): #should really specify what kind of exception you are catching!
    a = item.something()


with catch(Exception): #should really specify what kind of exception you are catching!
    b = item.something2()

b = re.sub(r'\W+', ' ', b)
b = b.strip()

with catch(Exception): #should really specify what kind of exception you are catching!
    c = item.something3()
    parsed_url = urlparse(b)
    if not bool(parsed_url.scheme):
        break

with catch(Exception): #should really specify what kind of exception you are catching!
    d = item.something4()
```

When you do `a = self.attrs(item.get("data-a"))` you are calling `item.get("data-a")` without any error checking and passing the return value into `self.attrs`, unless the result is callable trying to call it in `self.attrs` will raise a `TypeError`.  You would need to pass a callable that takes no arguments for the accepted answer to work, this only requires you have python version 2.7+ for support for the `with` statement.

By the way, if `item` is a `dict` then `dict.get` will never raise an exception, it is in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)

> `get(key[, default])`
>   Return the value for key if key is in the
>   dictionary, else default. If default is not given, it defaults to
>   `None`, **so that this method never raises a `KeyError`.**

Comment: Well its a good explanation. But 1 thing that I observed is that the function returns even if 1 of the function throws error. i.e. if a=item.something() fails it doesnt go to b = item.something2(). Which is an undesired behaviour. b = item.something2() should run even if a = item.something() throws exception

Comment: When the exception that is being handled is caught, the `with` block will end and execution will resume at the end of the block, so if each part is in it's own `with catch(...)` block then it should work correctly.  It doesn't mean "suppress all exceptions like this in this block" it is not that much then the original `try: except:`

Comment: I was getting the error issubclass() arg 1 must be a class

Comment: sorry my fault, needed to add `typ is not None and` before the `issubclass` check or just use `isinstance(err, self.check_err)` instead. Fixed now.

Comment: no no, see [my edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/38336776/2) that is what you need to change it to.