# Explicit Exception problem with try function

Tags: python

I have to run codes irrespective whether it fails or not. I'm using `ExplicitException`. Following is my code:

```
try:
    G.add_edge(data1[0][0],data1[1][0],weight=data1[2+i][0])
except ExplicitException:
    pass

try:
    G.add_edge(data1[0][0],data1[5][0],weight=data1[6+i][0])
except ExplicitException:
    pass

try:
    G.add_edge(data1[0][0],data1[9][0],weight=data1[10+i][0])
except ExplicitException:
    pass   

try:
    G.add_edge(data1[0][0],data1[13][0],weight=data1[14+i][0])
except ExplicitException:
    pass
```

I'm getting the following error:

> NameError: name 'ExplicitException' is not defined

would appreciate some help

Comment: What is `ExplicitException`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17322208/multiple-try-codes-in-one-block

Comment: I want to run multiple functions in the try block and ignore the function if it fails and move to the next one. I found the above link which mentions explicit exceptions

Comment: He was referring to explicit exception type, there is no `ExplicitException`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you got that idea from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17322283/4654175) answer. The idea the answer was trying to convey was that you can use an exception of your choice. In reality, there is no such exception as `ExplicitException`. You can use any exception from the [built-ins](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#bltin-exceptions) or define your own exception class.

You can also except the base class `Exception` and except all exceptions.

```py
try:
    # code
except Exception:
    pass
```

EDIT: While you can go about adding multiple try-except blocks, it is not a good practice. In your case, I believe your exception is because of some invalid value of `i` which would throw out of bounds exception. So you can avoid this by checking for the right values of `i` in if-else conditions.

If you're really into using try-except, try generalizing the lines and consolidating them into a loop. That would make the error handling easier. For example in the case above:

```py
for j in range(1,14,4):
    try:
        G.add_edge(data1[0][0],data1[j][0],weight=data1[1+j+i][0])
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Is there any faster way. I have hundreds of lines of code. Cant do all that manually?

Comment: `except` without specifying exception type also catches `sys.exit()` and `KeyboardInterrupt`. `except Exception` is better.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `ExplicitException`, in the thread you linked in the comments the OP is referring to explicit exception type. Since the code is repeating itself you can build a function and use it

```
def add_edge(first_indices, second_indices, weight_indices):
    try:
        G.add_edge(data1[first_indices[0]][first_indices[1]], data1[second_indices[0]][second_indices[1]], weight=data1[weight_indices[0]][weight_indices[1]])
    except (IndexError, TypeError):  # example to explicit exception
        pass

add_edge([0, 0], [1, 0], [2 + i, 0])
add_edge([0, 0], [5, 0], [6 + i, 0])
add_edge([0, 0], [9, 0], [10 + i, 0])
add_edge([0, 0], [13, 0], [14 + i, 0])
```