# Use 2 exceptions in a python function

Tags: python, median, mode, try-except

I want to write a function to calculate the mode of a column in a grouped by dataframe. If the values of a group has not a mode, the first exception: calculate the median and if the values of the group are all null values, the second exception:do nothing.
The sample dataframe is like below:

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'b':['b1','b1','b1','b1','b1','b1','b2','b2','b2','b2','b2','b2','b3','b3','b3'],'d':[0.1,None,0.12,None,None,0.13,1,2,1,1,None,None,None,None,None]})
```

The function is as follow:

```
def fill_mode(group):
    try:
        group['mode'] = mode(group['d'])
    except:
        not_nulls = group[~group['d'].isnull()]
        group['mode'] = median(not_nulls['d'])
    except:
        pass
    return group
```

And the apply function is as bellow:

```
dataframe = dataframe.groupby('b').apply(fill_mode)
```

Which raises this error :

> SyntaxError: default 'except:' must be last

The final output should be like this:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "second exception"?

Comment: Do you mean if you get an exception calculating the median? You should have a second `try/except` inside the first `except` block.

Comment: @Barmar Do you mean if you get an exception calculating the median? exactly

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17322208/multiple-try-codes-in-one-block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a second `try/except` block.

```
def fill_mode(group):
    try:
        group['mode'] = mode(group['d'])
    except:
        try:
            not_nulls = group[~group['d'].isnull()]
            group['mode'] = median(not_nulls['d'])
        except:
            pass
    return group
```