# How to combine multiple try and except in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list that will sometimes hold a single value, sometimes 2 or 3 values. I am assigning each of the values to a variable. If there is no value for the assigned position of the list, I want it to be a empty variable. Is there any way I can make this more efficient?

```
split = line.split(',')
try:
    var1 = split[0]
except IndexError:
    var1 = None
    
try:
    var2 = split[1]
except IndexError:
    var2 = None

try:
    var3 = split[2]
except IndexError:
    var3 = None
```

Comment: sounds like a usage of `dict`. can't you use `dict` to store these values instead of storing these in separate variables?

Comment: Related: [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/4518341)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple try codes in one block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17322208/multiple-try-codes-in-one-block)

Comment: `var1, var2, var3 = (split + [None] * 3)[:3]`.

Comment: If `line` is a string, `split[0]` will always exist. So is there a reason you're expecting an `IndexError`? For example, `''.split(',')` -> `['']`

Answer (score 1):

```
split = line.split(',')
variables = [None, None, None]


for i in range(len(split)):
        variables[i] = split[i]

var1, var2, var3 = variables
```

**Edit** (after @ekhumoro):

```
split = line.split(',')
variables = [None, None, None]
variables[:len(split)] = split
var1, var2, var3 = variables
```

Comment: `vars[:len(split)] = split`.

Comment: [`vars()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) is a builtin, so it'd be better to use a different name, to avoid shadowing. C.f. this problem: [TypeError: 'list' object is not callable in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31087111/4518341)

Answer (score 0):

You can use *generator expression* (or *list comprehension*) with conditional check to see if the index exists in the list. If exists, return element at that index, else return `None`. Here I am limiting my *generator expression* to return `n` (which is 3 in your case) values, and you can unpack and save these values in `n` variables.

For example:

```
my_list = [1] # List with just one element
n = 3  # Number of variables in which you want to fill the values

var1, var2, var3 = (my_list[i] if i < len(my_list) else None for i in range(n))

print(var1, var2, var3)
# prints: (1, None, None)
```

Refer [Generator Expressions and List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions) for more details.

Comment: @pcct2019 Did this answer and other answers here helped you? If yes, please upvote the answers by hitting the "up" arrow on the left of the answers. You can also mark the best answer as accepted by hitting "tick" icon. It helps answerer with reputation gain of +10 for each upvote and +15 for accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're actually trying to accomplish*, it might be better to **not** use individual variables. For example, you could use [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get), which returns `None` if the given key is not in the dict.

```
for line in 'a,b,c', 'd,e', 'f':
    split = line.split(',')
    d = {i: v for i, v in enumerate(split)}
    print(d, ' -> ', d.get(0), d.get(1), d.get(2))
```

Output:

```
{0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'}  ->  a b c
{0: 'd', 1: 'e'}  ->  d e None
{0: 'f'}  ->  f None None
```

---

You could also consider using unpacking:

```
for line in 'a,b,c', 'd,e', 'f':
    var1, *others = line.split(',')
    print(var1, others)
```

Output:

```
a ['b', 'c']
d ['e']
f []
```

---

By the way, note that `split[0]` will always exist, so I'm not sure why you're expecting an `IndexError`. For example:

```
>>> ''.split(',')
['']
```

* See some related ideas at [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/4518341) and more broadly, [how to avoid the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832)