# Selenium. Unable to locate element from the html website

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Here's the link of the website I'm trying to scrape (I'm training for the moment, nothing fancy):

[link](https://fr.hotels.com/)

Here's my script, he's quite long but nothing too complicated :

```
from selenium import webdriver



if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Web Scraping application started")

    PATH = "driver\chromedriver.exe"


    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
    options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    options.add_argument("--window-size=1200,900")
    options.add_argument('enable-logging')

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=PATH)

    driver.get('https://fr.hotels.com/')
    driver.maximize_window()

    destination_location_element = driver.find_element_by_id("qf-0q-destination")
    check_in_date_element = driver.find_element_by_id("qf-0q-localised-check-in")
    check_out_date_element = driver.find_element_by_id("qf-0q-localised-check-out")


    search_button_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="hds-marquee"]/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div[4]/button')

    print('Printing type of search_button_element')
    print(type(search_button_element))

    destination_location_element.send_keys('Paris')
    check_in_date_element.clear()
    check_in_date_element.send_keys("29/05/2021")
    check_out_date_element.clear()
    check_out_date_element.send_keys("30/05/2021")



    close_date_window = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[7]/div[4]/button')

    print('Printing type of close_date_window')
    print(type(close_date_window))

    close_date_window[0].click()

    search_button_element.click()

    time.sleep(10)

    hotels = driver.find_element_by_class_name('hotel-wrap')

    print("\n")

    i = 1

    for hotel in hotels:

        try:
            print(hotel.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="listings"]/ol/li['+str(i)+']/article/section/div/h3/a').text)
            print(hotel.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="listings"]/ol/li[' + str(i) + ']/article/section/div/address/span').text)

        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)
            print('Failed to extract data from element.')

        i = i +1

        print('\n')

    driver.close()

    print('Web Scraping application completed')
```

And here's the error I get :

```
  File "hotelscom.py", line 21, in <module>
    destination_location_element = driver.find_element_by_id("qf-0q-destination")
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="qf-0q-destination"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.85)
```

Any idea how to fix that ? I don't understand why it get me this error because in the html code, there is this syntax. But i guess I'm wrong.

Comment: What is your location? Country?

Comment: France, what for ?

Comment: Locators depend on location

Comment: @FalconMelee did you try my solution?

Comment: Yeah but th script doesn't find `destination_location_element` anymore, so I replace your `element` by `destination_location_element` but it doesn't work either

Comment: Check my answer, I summarised problems related to your code and the site itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple problems with your code and the site.

**SITE PROBLEMS**

**1** The site is located on multiple servers and different servers have different html code. I do not know if it depends on location or not.

**2** The version I have solution for has few serious bugs (or maybe those are features). Among them:

- When you press Enter it starts hotels search when a date field is opened and and you just want to close this date field. So, it is a problem to close input fields in a traditional way.
- `clear()` of Selenium does not work as it is supposed to work.

**BUGS IN YOUR CODE**

**1** You are defining window size in options and you are maximizing the window immediately after site is opened. Use only one option

**2** You are entering dates like "29/05/2021", but sites recognises formats only like: "05/30/2021". It is a big difference

**3** You are not using any waits and they are extremely important.

**4** Your locators are wrong and unstable. Even locators with `id` did not always work for me because if you will make a search, there are two elements for some of them. So I replaces them with `css` selectors.

Please note that my solution works only for an old version of site. If you want to a specific version to be opened you will need either:

- Get the site by a direct **ip address**, like  driver.get('site ip address')
- Implement a strategy in your framework which recognises which site version is opened and applies inputs depending on it.

#### SOLUTION

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Web Scraping application started")
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    options.add_argument("--window-size=1200,900")
    options.add_argument('enable-logging')

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path='/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver')

    driver.get('https://fr.hotels.com/')
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)

    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#qf-0q-destination")))
    destination_location_element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#qf-0q-destination")
    destination_location_element.send_keys('Paris, France')
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".widget-autosuggest.widget-autosuggest-visible table tr")))
    destination_location_element.send_keys(Keys.TAB)  # workaround to close destination field
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".widget-query-sub-title").click()
    wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".widget-query-group.widget-query-destination [aria-expanded=true]")))

    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#qf-0q-localised-check-in")))
    check_in_date_element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#qf-0q-localised-check-in")
    check_in_date_element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'a')  # workaround to replace clear() method
    check_in_date_element.send_keys(Keys.DELETE)  # workaround to replace clear() method
    # check_in_date_element.click()
    check_in_date_element.send_keys("05/30/2021")

    # wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#qf-0q-localised-check-out")))
    check_out_date_element = driver.find_element_by_id("qf-0q-localised-check-out")
    check_out_date_element.click()
    check_out_date_element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'a')
    check_out_date_element.send_keys(Keys.DELETE)
    check_out_date_element.send_keys("05/31/2021")
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".widget-query-sub-title").click()  # workaround to close end date
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#hds-marquee button"))).click()
```

Spent on this few hours, the task seemed just interesting for me.
It works for this UI:
[image]

The code can still be optimised. It's up to you.

**UPDATE:**

I found out that the site has at least three home pages with three different `Destination` and other fields locators.
The easiest workaround that came into my mind is something like this:

```
try:
    element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#qf-0q-destination")
    if element.is_displayed():
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#qf-0q-destination")))
        destination_location_element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#qf-0q-destination")
        print("making input to Destination field of site 1")
        destination_location_element.send_keys('Paris, France')
        # input following data
except:
    print("Page 1 not found")
try:
    element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name=q-destination-srs7]")
    if element.is_displayed():
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name=q-destination-srs7]")))
        destination_location_element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name=q-destination-srs7]")
        print("making input to Destination field of site 2")
        destination_location_element.send_keys('Paris, France')
        # input following data
except:
    print("Page 2 is not found")
try:
    element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("form[method=GET]>div>._1yFrqc")
    if element.is_displayed():
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "form[method=GET]>div>._1yFrqc")))
        destination_location_element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("form[method=GET]>div>._1yFrqc")
        print("making input to Destination field of site 3")
        destination_location_element.send_keys('Paris, France')
        # input following data
except:
    print("Page 3 is not found")
```

But the best solution would be to have a direct access to a specific server that has only one version available.

Please also note that if you access the site by a direct link for France: https://fr.hotels.com/?pos=HCOM_FR&locale=fr_FR your input dates will be as you initially specified, for example 30/05/2021.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! That's a wonderful answer. For now I have just one question : `chromium.chromedriver` ? That's a new one for me :)

Comment: Use chromedriver.exe as you did previously. I am using Linux.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I get this error :   `File "hotelscom.py", line 28, in <module>
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#qf-0q-destination")))
  File "C:\Users\evanalonso\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:`

Comment: It may happen because the site you are opening has a different DOM (problem #1 of this site). Check this on how to make your strategy with a few try blocks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17322208/multiple-try-codes-in-one-block

Comment: @vitaliis your answer is extremely impressive!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[contains(@class,'destination')]/input[@name='q-destination']")
```

Also please add wait after you maximize the window

Comment: It doesn't find the xpath, I tried this : `destination_location_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='qf-0q-destination']")` and it seems to work. But I guess right click to copy xpath dosn't seems the right coice bcause now it doesn't find this : `close_date_window = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[7]/div[4]/button')`

Comment: Try this xpath: .//button[@class='widget-overlay-close']

Comment: I don't understand, now it's `destination_location_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='qf-0q-destination']")` whose not working again. When I change the `close_date_window`, `destination_location_element` stopped working. I don't understand.

Comment: I land on 2 different websites when i run my code. Could be location specific.

Comment: My bad, I remove my modification on `close_date_window` but `destination_location_element` don't seems to work now. I don't understand, earlier, it work and I just have another error on `close_date_window` so I assume `destination_location_element` was working.

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: I tried right click -> copy xpath and -> `destination_location_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="qf-0q-destination"]')` but it doesn't work either. I'm lost ^^

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232961/discussion-between-itronic1990-and-falconmelee).

Comment: @itronic1990 The site has, not two, but at least three landing pages. The locator you found is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a wait / sleep before finding the element.
So, just add this:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "qf-0q-destination")))
element.click()
```

to use this you will have to use the following imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as E
```

Comment: `qf-0q-destination` doesn't look like a static ID

Comment: I tried this and it worked on my computer, so it does.

Comment: @Prophet Your locator is correct, but the problem with this site is that it has at least three different home pages.